# Android Firebase push notification custom sound is not working

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

1)This is my fire base class in this class message is received.

```
public class FirebaseMessagingPushService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        Log.d("Sound Bell", "From: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getSound());


        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            sendNotification(remoteMessage);
        }

    }

    private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
        final String ChannelID = "my_channel_01"; //this is my channel id name
        String title = data.get("title");
        String message = data.get("body");
        String sound = remoteMessage.getNotification().getSound();
        String action = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();
        String Notification = remoteMessage.getNotification().getChannelId();



        Uri sounduri = Uri.parse(String.format("android.resource://%s/%s/%s", this.getPackageName(), "raw", sound));
        Log.i("hellosound", String.valueOf(sounduri));
        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.getDefaultType(sounduri));

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, ChannelID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logomadhuras)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                        .bigText(message))
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        int notificationId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        mBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (manager != null) {
    ***********Here i create channel*******
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(ChannelID,
                        "Human Readable channel id",
                        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
                AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                        .build();
                channel.setShowBadge(true);
                channel.setSound(alarmSound, attributes);
                manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

            }

            manager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
        }
    }

}
```

2)This below code is defined in manifest file.

```
   <meta-data
              android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
              android:value="my_channel_01" />
    <service
            android:name=".FirebaseMessagingPushService"
            android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

3) I pass both channel id and sound in json file of fire base..

PROBLEM - I want my custom sound in my application but when i received message from firebase i 
        can not get custom sound but my mobile ringtone is playing on message received..Please give me solution how to set custom sound..And my mobile version is android pie.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
Uri sound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.notification_mp3);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel("YOUR_CHANNEL_ID",
            "YOUR CHANNEL NAME",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)

        AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                .build();
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, 
                context.getString(R.string.app_name),
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

        mChannel.setDescription(msg);
        mChannel.enableLights(true);
        mChannel.enableVibration(true);
        mChannel.setSound(sound, attributes); // IMPORTANT

        if (mNotificationManager != null)
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }
```

Hope this will work!